# «Вообще» как усилительная частица

Tags: семантика, частица

Уважаемые завсегдатаи данного форума, прошу вас разъяснить мне, в чем функция частицы "вообще" в нижеуказанных предложениях?

**1.** Вася может не есть день, Антон — два дня, а Сергей **вообще** может не есть неделю.
**2.** Кровать, говорите, неудобная... Вот я в детстве **вообще** на полу спал.

Comment: Что-то со знаками препинания происходит... Скопируйте в Word, он покажет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала решим задачу в самом **общем виде** (а в дальнейшем можем пользоваться этой схемой в других темах с наречием "вообще").

**1. ОБЩЕЕ РЕШЕНИЕ**

Представим себе **общее/целое множество**, включающее некоторое количество **частных элементов**. Это множество в различных темах **([по толковому словарю](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5&all=x))** можно назвать **по-разному:** (1) в общем, отвлеченно/абстрактно, (2) в большинстве случаев, обычно, в любом случае (3) всегда, в любое время,  (4) полностью/совершенно, (5) в итоге.

Также возможны **другие** частные темы, но тематику в каждом случае надо обозначить.

**2. ПРИМЕРЫ**

Здесь можно увидеть **оценочное** значение наречия "вообще": в одном случае мы оцениваем **ВРЕМЯ** (продолжительность), а в другом случае оцениваем **УДОБСТВО**. Но делаем мы это, сравнивая **частные** случаи/случай и **обобщенный** нами случай (с пометкой ***вообще***).

(1) *Вася может не есть день, Антон – два дня, а Сергей **вообще** может не есть неделю.*

Обобщенная оценка времени: **очень (действительно) долго**. Такая метка относится к последнему из трех сообщений. Один день, два дня – частные случаи.
*Сергей **вообще** может не есть неделю* (вот это действительно **очень** долго).

(2) *Кровать говорите неудобная ... Вот я в детстве **вообще** на полу спал.*

Обобщенная оценка удобства: **очень (действительно) неудобно**. Такая метка относится ко второму сообщению. Неудобная кровать – частный случай.
*Вот я в детстве **вообще** на полу спал* (вот это действительно **очень** неудобно).

**Вывод**: наречие "вообще" может иметь усилительное значение **максимально/очень** (действительно долго, действительно неудобно).

**3. ПРИМЕЧАНИЯ**

1. Отметим, что в толковых словарях не указана **усилительная** функция наречия "вообще", соответственно **частицей** это слово не называют. Поэтому такой вывод можно сделать только на основе **рассуждения**.
2. А что указано **В СЛОВАРЕ?** Пожалуй, ближе всего значение (4): **ВООБЩЕ**. 4. ***Совсем, совершенно***. Это в. запрещено строго-настрого. Сегодня в. не спал. Он в. перестал здороваться.

Частные случаи здесь не обозначены, но **оценочное** значение наречия присутствует (полностью, абсолютно, совершенно). Тогда можно ответить так: **усилительное значение** наречия "вообще" обозначено в значении 4 по словарю: **совсем, совершенно**. А также: максимально, в полной мере, очень.

*Сергей может не есть **очень** долго – неделю. Вот я в детстве спал **очень** неудобно – на полу.*

3. Можно ли заменить **ВООБЩЕ** на обычную **усилительную частицу ДАЖЕ**? Далеко не всегда, что видно на различных примерах, в том числе из литературы. А главное, нужно объяснить, откуда у слова "вообще"  **усилительное** значение, как это связано с **семантикой** прилагательного "общий", с корнем этого слова.

**4. Примеры из литературы**

*Кому и зачем я пишу … Кто поверит мне, если я и сама себе не вполне доверяю? Дочитаешь ли ты все это до конца? Прочитает ли это **вообще** кто-нибудь?*  (Людмила Улицкая, 2000).

Табаки достал блокнот и черкал в нем что-то ручкой, выуженной из-за уха. – Так-так, – бормотал он. – Несомненно… и это тоже не забудем. Еще бы. А вот это **вообще** недопустимо… (Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором…).

Comment: Спасибо! Подход к объяснению у Вас необычный. Все четко и по существу!

Comment: Спасибо вам! Вопрос был очень интересный и непростой.

Answer (score 1):

По смыслу тут можно заменить на "более того", "скажу больше", "даже больше":

```
А Сергей может, скажу больше, не есть неделю
Вот я в детстве, скажу больше, на полу спал
```

Соответственно функция в максимальном усилении сопоставления с какой-то ситуацией.
Кто-то иногда спал на полу, а я, более того, спал на полу всегда

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, ***вообще*** в приведённых предложениях равно по значению частице ***даже***, употребляющейся для подчёркивания высокой степени проявления какого-л. признака путём указания на лицо, предмет, действие и т.п.

Ср.:

---

*Вася может не есть день, Антон — два дня, а Сергей **вообще** может не есть неделю*

и

*Вася может не есть день, Антон — два дня, а Сергей может не есть **даже** неделю*;

---

*Кровать, говорите, неудобная... Вот я в детстве **вообще** на полу спал*

и

*Кровать, говорите, неудобная... Вот я в детстве **даже** на полу спал*.

---